# clBuildProgram exception "executed long jump"

Tags: c, exception, opencl

For my thesis I have to write an algorithm in OpenCL. However, when compiling the cl file I got a bunch of errors. I fixed them all but now I get the following problem when I run the program and I have no idea what exactly is wrong.

[image: opencl problenm]

debug4 is printed. "Er is een 'long jump' uitgevoerd." is dutch and it means "A 'long jump' was executed."

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Seems like a bug in OpenCL implementation. What is the platform you are using (e.g. nvidia/amd/intel and its version)?

Comment: NVIDIA GPU Computing SDK 4.2
Thx already for the help, i find this such an odd error. Maybe i'll try reinstalling the sdk.

Comment: "long jumps" are the old school way of implementing exception handling. Do you have this error for any program you try to compile? If no you should try to find the culprit line(s) using a dichotomy by removing half the code and checking if the error is still here.

Comment: Ok, i'll try that. It's indeed only my self written OpenCL code that gives this problem, other OpenCL code compiles fine.

Comment: I had exactly the same problem using OpenCl 1.0 for SDK 4.2 too. As Serious suggested, I found the faulty line using dichotomy: it was caused by a recursive call (unsupported in OpenCL). The compiler did not bother to warn me...